# getInflationRewards returning 0.04% for stake yield

Tags: staking

Quick question , I am trying to calculate staking rewards for an account on a validator. For such thing I am using a simple TS script that users @solana/web3.js package. I had understoo that the method `getInflationReward` (https://solana.com/es/docs/rpc/http/getinflationreward) would give me such info but the amount field in the resulting data is just 0.04% with respect with the staked amount and I don't know if that should be correct. In order to obtain this percentage I just do (rewards * 100) / (postbalance - rewards). Can you guys tell me if my logic is incorrect plz ? Also, sorry if this is not the correct channel

Answer (score 1):

`getInflationReward` only gives the reward information *for a given epoch*, as stated in the docs:

> Returns the inflation / staking reward for a list of addresses for an epoch

So if you're getting 0.04% for an epoch, and there are ~182 epochs per year, that gives a yearly return of ~7.3%.